# Passing one or multiple string parameters in controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this controller method

```
//[HttpGet("{id}")] 
public IActionResult Nav(string id)
{
    return HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode($"Hello {id}");
    //return Content("Here's the ContentResult message.");
}
```

that i want to pass a string parameter and display it when i visit the controller method `https://localhost:7123/Home/Nav/Logan`. I get this error.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'
```

I am using asp net core 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is throwing this error as you are returning a string when it expects an IActionResult. You can easily solve this by returning `Ok($"Hello {id}");`

Comment: How come this is not possible `public IActionResult Nav(string id, int num)
    {
  return Ok($"Hello {id} {num}");
    }`

Comment: Sorry this works `https://localhost:7123/Home/Nav/6?num=5`

Comment: What you are referring to is routing. Your original question has `[HttpGet("{id}")]` which means that the action method is expecting something like `/Home/Nav/{id}`. If you do not declare a route, your url would be `https://localhost:7123/Home/Nav?id=6&num=5`

Comment: @Gandalf if you agree with my comment could you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain.

- When you perform following action.

```
return HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode($"Hello {id}");
```

This will return string and your method expect IActionResult so it get failed.

#### Solution 1

```
public string Nav(string id)
{
    return HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode($"Hello {id}");   
}
```

Now if you two paramter then you have to configure route that way. Default route only expect one Id.

```
[HttpGet("Nav/{id}/{two}")]
public string Nav(string id,string two)
{
    return HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode($"Hello {id},{two}");   
}
```

#### Solution 2

You can use Content or Ok Result and provide your output.

```
public IActionResult Nav(string id)
{
    return Ok(HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode($"Hello {id}"));
}
```

Comment: In the first solution, can i have a parameter of type string and int or list? I am trying this `public string Nav(string id, string two)
    {
  return two;
        //return Content("Here's the ContentResult message.");
    }` but fails

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way. This is the url `https://localhost:7123/Home/Nav/6?num=5&third=3`

and this is the method

```
public IActionResult Nav(string id, int num, string third)
{
    return Ok($"Hello {id} {num} {third}");
}
```